# How to map spring cloud server plain text files to @Value annotation in the spring cloud client side

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I am currently able to get my spring cloud plain text files with:
http://localhost:8888/config-server-client/native/ng.conf?useDefaultLabel

I would like to know if there is a way to map plain text files to a @Value annotation, something like this:

```
@Value("${ng.conf}")
private Resource serverConfFile;
```

or:

```
@Value("ng.conf")
private String serverConfFileContent;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

Comment: With the above link, you can map properties( if u have a lot of them) with a common prefix into a JAVA object. That is how generally spring open-source projects like Spring Cloud Netflix, Spring Cloud Config do it.

Comment: I understand but what I am trying to do is to map a plain text file from a spring cloud app (server) into my spring cloud client app ... The link you provided doesn't cover, it doesn't even mention spring cloud.

Comment: is it a properties file or a yaml file?

Comment: It is a plain text file, not a configuration file. It could be a simple README file or a json file. Please see:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/789

Comment: looking at the code, it does not seem its implemented.
If you look at the code, the response from the configServer is a list of property sources.
 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/environment/PropertySource.java

Comment: This is currently not implemented in Spring Cloud config. Github issue - 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/789

Comment: Leaving the comment, if anyone with same issue comes around this thread.